# Oracle -- FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to evaluate the execution time of the query by adding the ordered hint to it.

```
SELECT ordered count(*) FROM T1, T2, T3
WHERE T1.col1=T3.col11 
AND T2.col1=T3.col12 
AND T1.col2=1
```

running my statement keeps giving

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 20
```

while it's supposed to run the statement properly

Comment: From the Oracle documentation it looks like it's just a syntax error, it has to be /*+ORDERED */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ count(*) FROM T1, T2, T3
WHERE T1.col1=T3.col11 
AND T2.col1=T3.col12 
AND T1.col2=1
```

And look at the execution plan to make sure it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Hints have their [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D316D545-89E2-4D54-977F-FC97815CD62E):

```
select /*+ ordered */ count(*)
…
```

Also, switching to ANSI join syntax as suggested would be a good idea.